# How to update a branch in repo in GIT

Tags: git

I have created a branch in repository and I did pull followed by push but the branch is still showing 32/332 behind and ahead status. 
How to keep my branch updated like 32/0 like 32 are the changes I made and 0 ahead of me

Comment: what is the output of "git status" on the branch

Answer (score 0):

Try and see if a `git pull --rebase` would help

That would replay your local commits on top of the remote one.

Check first that your branch is indeed associated to a remote tracking one with:

```
git branch -avv
```